# How to stop people from registering other people

Tags: civievent

There are a number of places where CiviCRM gives a user the opportunity to register someone else for an event.  In our case, this is undesirable behaviour.

We have tried using CSS to hide those messages, by replacing the .msg-text with text of our own, but inevitably this also causes us to hide important messages that shouldn't be hidden.

Is there a way in Civi to just prevent registering other people altogether?  Or on a per-event basis perhaps?

Specific examples:

- If you have already registered for an event, and you go to the event page, Civi gives you an option to register someone else.  So we used CSS to hide .msg-text.
- However, if you have an event that has a registration limit, the same .msg-text CSS placeholder is used to say the event is full.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: This should really be a feature of CiviCRM, some kind of option in the event setup to limit registration to authenticated users (whether by login or by personalized link). Maybe you want to add this feature or sponsor it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, its difficult to hide the message from the status using CSS. You write JS to remove the  tag inside the .msg-text. But the user will still be able to register using the URL

We have an extension that over-rides the status message and restricts the user to registering using cid=0 from the URL.

Comment: Thank you Pradeep.  It's helpful to know I'm not crazy!  :)  Is it a public extension?  I tried searching in gitlab and civi extensions directory but didn't find anything.

Comment: It has some complex code in it, will need to do some clean-up so that I can make it available for public